# How to grab color mapping from matplotlib pie chart in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

From pandas documentation on creating pie charts from data frames:

I have the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mass': [0.330, 4.87 , 5.97],
                   'radius': [2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1]},
                  index=['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth'])
plot = df.plot.pie(y='mass', figsize=(5, 5))
```

This create a pie chart of planets by mass:

[image]

Now I add an argument in the plotting line to specify I want to use a specific Seaborn color palette "Set2":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mass': [0.330, 4.87 , 5.97],
                   'radius': [2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1]},
                  index=['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth'])
plot = df.plot.pie(y='mass', figsize=(5, 5), colors=sns.color_palette('Set2'))
```

And we get the same plot, but now with a different color palette used:

[image]

When I run each of these code chunks, with each color palette, the color mapping with the planet names remains the same, telling me that the mapping is based on the value assigned to each planet name.

What I want to do is "grab" that mapping as a dictionary, such that it can be used in a for loop.

To explain the goal here, I have a data frame containing many different mass values assigned to each planet, from different analyses. This means that experiment "A" had these specific mass values for our three planets here, and experiment "B" had different values for the three planets, and experiment "C" had another different set of values of the three planets, etc. Each of the dataframes with these experiment values are generated from a for loop, iterating through each experiment. For each experiment I want to create a pie chart with the mass values. The main point here, is that I want all of the color mappings for the planets to be the same for each generated plot in the for loop. And so the idea is to "grab" the color mapping dictionary from the first iteration of the for loop, and then apply that exact color mapping to each following iteration of the for loop, assuming there will always just be three planets in the experiment. How can I do this, specifically getting that color mapping dictionary from the first iteration?

Comment: To grab the dictionary from the plot legend, you can do `handles, labels = plot.get_legend_handles_labels(); color_mapping = {planet: handle.get_facecolor() for handle, planet in zip(handles, labels)}`.

Comment: So then `color_mapping` needs to be entered into the `cmap` argument in `plot = df.plot.pie(y='mass', figsize=(5, 5), colors=sns.color_palette('Set2'))`? Such that we get our color mapping dictionary and then run `plot = df.plot.pie(y='mass', figsize=(5, 5), colors=sns.color_palette('Set2'), cmap = color_mapping)`? I tried this and did not get the intended results and got the warnings `UserWarning: 'color' and 'colormap' cannot be used simultaneously. Using 'color' warnings.warn(`

Comment: No, you need either to set the colors, e.g. `df.plot.pie(..., colors=df.index.map(color_mapping))` or a colormap: `df.plot.pie(..., cmap='Set2')`. You can't do both.  The most-straightforward solution, is @Keegan Kozler 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the mapping as a dictionary and then define the plot colors as an array.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'mass': [0.330, 4.87 , 5.97],
        'radius': [2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1]
    },
    index=['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth'])

color_mapping = dict(zip(df.index, sns.color_palette('Set2')))

# this could be executed in a loop...
plot_colors = [color_mapping[planet] for planet in df.index]
plot = df.plot.pie(y='mass', figsize=(5, 5), colors=plot_colors)
```

Comment: A shorter alternative for `plot_colors = [color_mapping[planet] for planet in df.index]` is `plot_colors = df.index.map(color_mapping)`.

Comment: When I tried `plot_colors = [color_mapping[planet] for planet in df_pc.index]` on my own code and I got the error: `KeyError: 8`. I then tried `plot_colors = df.index.map(color_mapping)` on my own code and got the error: `TypeError: Expected tuple, got float` pointing to that line.

Comment: This works with your example here, but for some reason it is just not registering in my actual code, where I set `color=plot_colors`, and yet in the for loop the plot color labeling is still just based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.colormaps['Set2'].colors` will give you the colors of the palette as an array.

If you need a dictionary,

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth']
pallette = matplotlib.colormaps['Set2'].colors
dict(zip(planets, pallette))
```

Comment: Does this just assign each planet name to the first three colors listed in `Set2`? What is the mapping based on? And how can I actually use this in the plotting? Would I set as `cmap = dict(zip(planets, pallette))`?